# Flutter Firebase Authentication error on Ios

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, authentication

call  `await firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();`  causes error:

[firebase_auth/admin-restricted-operation] ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION.

Email auth provider and Anonymous option in Firebase console are enabled.

Error happens only on iOS, on Android it's ok.

How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't the correct GoogleService-Info.plist in your project.

Read the iOS installation: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/ios